# Broken link to 'sbpl' planner package

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, sbpl-lattice-planner, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to install the 'sbpl_lattice_planner' package ...

in ROS Fuerte. It appears to need a package called 'sbpl' appears to be broken.

Attempts to get it from other sources also led nowhere!

Thanks!

MORE DETAILS ON WHAT I DID AS A RESPONSE TO JEREMY'S RESPONSE ...
I was trying to follow the sbpl_lattice planner  ROS wiki instructions for installation and execution. I did the following:
a) acquired the "navigation _experimental" stack (for fuerte)
b) tried to execute the following two suggested commands:
rosmake sbpl_lattice_planner
roslaunch sbpl_lattice_planner move_base_sbpf_fake_localization_2.5cm.launch
c) the compilation did not complete because it pointed to a missing 'sbpl' package. After extensive search resulting in the discovery of several broken links (including Maxim Likhachev's site).
d) after further search, found 'sbpl' as part of the "footsteps planner" package. Downloaded it and did a separate compilation and integration into the 'sbpl_lattice_planner'.
e) I thought I had solved the problem until I ran the roslaunch command. This led to several errors due to inability to execute the required Python commands.

JEREMY: I will try what you suggested (apt-get install ros-fuerte-sbpl).

UPDATE:
Just finished executing apt-get install ros-fuerte-sbpl. No luck ... details below ...
'rosmake sbpl_lattice_planner' command goes through without any errors.
'roslaunch sbpl_lattice_planner move_base_sbpf_fake_localization_2.5cm.launch' command fails with the message 'ResourceNotFound: sbpl'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62414/broken-link-to-%27sbpl%27-planner-package/) by [mosfet2u](https://answers.ros.org/users/4418/mosfet2u/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think sbpl is available as an Ubuntu package.  Have you tried `apt-get install ros-fuerte-sbpl`?  I see that the source-code link on the [sbpl wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/sbpl) is broken.  It looks to me like the current version of this package can be found on [github](https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl) instead.

What issues are you having, specifically?

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1